# How to access VBScript's Err object in C# code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, com, vbscript

I see there is a problem with the error handling in VBScript, So I would like to fix this using c# code (COM). Here, I need to access Err object of VBScript in c#.net code. I did add the reference namespace **VBScript_Global** to the project, but VBScript_Global.ErrObj is an abstract class, so could not access it. Is there a way that c# code can watch the Err.Number.

Let me put it more clear,
In VB6, we have On Error GoTo  in which if there is a runtime error it automatically drops into error handling code and we can report the error there and do appropriate action.

The same is true with .net and Java (it may be try/catch there).

Where as in VBScript, we have On Error Resume Next (it does not support GoTo ).
On Error Resume Next just moves the controller to the next statement and continue with the execution. Where, we need to explicitly check whether Err.number <> 0 after each statement in the code, which is not feasible to implement.

So I want a generic approach in VBScript, if there is a runtime error, then I should be able to report it somehow.

I thought of writing a dll in c#.net which always checks for the Err.Number of VBScript and report when there is an error occurred. Is this possible? Or my approach is wrong?
Any other alternative suggestions/ideas to handle this situation is appreciated. Thanks.

If the dll cannot do what am looking for, is there a way I can always check whether Err.number of VBScript is NOT 0 out side the VBScript?

Comment: How do you execute the vbscript code from your C# code?  You can't get any useful error info if you use the Process class, other than the ExitCode property.  Which is often sufficient.

Comment: What exactly is the "problem with the error handling in VBScript"? Why have you decided to fix it by adding another component instead of preventing the original problem?

Answer (score 1):

VBScript executes in a separate environment.  You cannot access an intrinsic VBScript object outside of VBScript, or more appropriately, Windows Script Host.